# Existe alguma API para criar um serviço semelhante Directory API da Google?

Tags: java, rest, annotation, javadoc

Acho muito interessante o Directory API da Google por reunir documentação e ambiente de testes de uma forma fácil objetiva e bem organizada.

Gostaria de saber se há algum plugin semelhante que possa ser adicionado a uma aplicação Java para gerar automaticamente esse ambiente. Para ficar mais claro eu citaria o Javadoc. Com base nas anotações e comentários ele é capaz de gerar a documentação. Isso já seria boa parte do conteúdo que podemos encontrar no Directory API. Já o ambiente de testes poderia para as funções REST dependeria da notação de REST, identificar a URL do servidor e montar a URL de requisição. O Javadoc não contempla tudo.

O que eu queria exatamente erá montar um [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/insert) privado, onde ele tivesse como conteúdo a documentação do meu projeto.

Alguém sabe se existe isso pronto em algum lugar ou se realmente é necessário criar isso na mão? Se existe, qual o programa ou plugin é usado para fazer isso?

Comment: Tudo em uma única solução não conheço, além de depender de ferramentas que já utiliza, como os *reports* gerados por padrão em ferramentas de *build* como *maven* e *gradle*. Para a parte de documentação/teste/mock da API REST recomendo dar uma olhada no [swagger](http://swagger.io/)

Answer (score 0):

Talvez o gerador de sites do Maven possa te ajudar nessa tarefa, pois com ele é possível gerar sites com a documentação do projeto e itens adicionais, de uma olhada:

[Maven - Creating a Site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-site.html)

Comment: Estou procurando na realidade é um gerador mesmo de documentação do REST. Vou verificar mais sobre isso

Answer (score 0):

O ApiDoc é uma biblioteca que pode ser usada para gerar a documentação dos serviços rest.

Essa ferramenta além de ter suporte a documentação, ainda conta com o sandbox que é um ambiente de testes que pode ser usado para testar as próprias chamadas.

Usei em Symfony, porém pode ser usado também em outros frameworks ou mesmo usado sem framework, seu uso se baseia em Annotations, através de "comentários" você consegue documentar o seu rest e também o ambiente de testes.

A biblioteca é bem completa e possui uma boa documentação (em inglês), para obter mais informações sobre a biblioteca basta acessar o [site do apiDoc](http://apidocjs.com/), se estiver usando o symfony pode usar o [NelmioApiDocBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/NelmioApiDocBundle/index.html).

A biblioteca permite ainda a customização do template, para a criação de um layout personalizado.